# What are these mathfrak/mathcal/mathbb fonts?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, alphabet, fourier

I recently came across [this preprint of Pierre Berthelot](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/pierre.berthelot/publis/Cohomologie_Rigide_I.pdf), and became a little obsessed with the very pretty typesetting.
I determined that the text font is New Century Schoolbook or something very close, which `\usepackage{fouriernc}` does a fine job of emulating.
However, one thing which this package does *not* capture are the preprint's neat `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak`, and `\mathbb` fonts.
Here are some screenshots of those:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The `pdffonts` tool claims that these are "Atalante" or "Beaulieu" fonts, but a google search for these did not turn up anything useful (although a [recording of a Tolkein poem](https://glaemscrafu.jrrvf.com/english/atalante.html) in one of his obscure Elvish languages was quite interesting!).
Any help on how to use these fonts would be appreciated.

Comment: A good resource for tracking down math font possibilties is pp. 7 to 12 of the user guide of the [mathalpha](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) (aka `mathalfa`) package.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the suggestion! I have used the `mathalpha` package in the past  so this was one of the places I looked; however the fonts used in Berthelot's preprint don't look to me like any of those appearing in the `mathalfa` user guide.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. The normal-weight and bold-weight fraktur letters of Mathmematica Fraktur look to me like reasonable candidates for the `a` and `m` letters  in your screenshot. However, to each their own.